# Seleccionar valores de una fila al hacer click

Tags: jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Se dispone de una tabla con varias filas y columnas, deseo que con el mouse haga click en una fila y me separa tres valores de las seis columnas que tengo. Pero, los valores obtenidos deben ser SOLO DE ESA FILA.

Anexo el código que tengo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataGrid tr").on('click', function() {
        var toma1 = "", toma2 = "", toma3 = ""; 
            $("#dataGrid").find("tr").each(function() {
                toma1 += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
                toma2 += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
                toma3 += $(this).find('td:eq(5)').html();
           }); 
        $("#respuesta").text(toma1 + toma2 + toma3);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataGrid">
         <tr>
            <td>1111111</td>
            <td>222222</td>
            <td>3333333</td>
            <td>4444444</td>
            <td>55555555</td>
            <td>66666</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  
  <label id="respuesta"><label>
```

Comment: ¿Porque los negativos? Esta pregunta no tiene nada de malo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes intentar es evitar el `each()`, porque eso hace que vayas a cada fila, cuando lo que quieres es solo de la fila en donde estas haciendo click. Basicamente solo borre la funcion `each()` de tu codigo y puse un par de filas mas para comprobar el ejemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataGrid tr").on('click', function() {
        var toma1 = "", toma2 = "", toma3 = ""; 
                toma1 += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
                toma2 += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
                toma3 += $(this).find('td:eq(5)').html();
 
        $("#respuesta").text(toma1 + toma2 + toma3);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataGrid">
         <tr>
            <td>a1111111</td>
            <td>a222222</td>
            <td>a3333333</td>
            <td>a4444444</td>
            <td>a55555555</td>
            <td>a66666</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>b1111111</td>
            <td>b222222</td>
            <td>b3333333</td>
            <td>b4444444</td>
            <td>b55555555</td>
            <td>b66666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1111111</td>
            <td>c222222</td>
            <td>c3333333</td>
            <td>c4444444</td>
            <td>c55555555</td>
            <td>c66666</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  
  <label id="respuesta"><label>
```

Comment: Ahora si está resuelto definitivamente el problema!!! Muchiisimas gracias Sr. Kenny Barrera, disculpe lo tardío de mi respuesta.

Comment: @peluca no hay problema. Que bueno que te ayudo. No olvides marcarla como aceptada si soluciono completamente tu problema.